# Kafka Connect FilePulse To Apply Filtrations on CSV file columns and load into a Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I'm loading CSV files contents into a Kafka topic using **FilePulse** connector and it's working fine. My CSV file contents sample is like below;

```
`reference_key,service_type,event_timestamp,cell_id,site_id,serial_no,model_no,tac,current_date
1124545422342,VAT,1672804433000,28668,ULG2866,,,,20230104
1124545422342,VAT,1672804497000,28668,ULG2866,,,,20230104
1124545422342,VAT,1672802056000,,,357416315997720F,,35741,20230104
0342455432268,VAT,1672802123000,,,357464315455830F,,35746,20230104
0342455432268,VAT,1672802335000,14458,ULG1445,,,,20230104
9907033485252,WHO,1672873387000,,,,,,20230104
9907033485252,WHO,1672873387000,,,,,,20230104
0,TAX,1672873451000,,,,,,20230104
5456035928014,ADD,1672873451000,,,,,,20230104
5648136134038,ADD,1672873451000,,,,,,20230104`
```

The Kafka Consumer output for the topic is listed below;

```
`{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"reference_key,service_type,event_timestamp,cell_id,site_id,serial_no,model_no,tac,current_date"}],"optional":false},"payload":{"reference_key,service_type,event_timestamp,cell_id,site_id,serial_no,model_no,tac,current_date":"124545422342,VAT,1672804433000,28668,ULG2866,,,,20230104"}}
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"reference_key,service_type,event_timestamp,cell_id,site_id,serial_no,model_no,tac,current_date"}],"optional":false},"payload":{"reference_key,service_type,event_timestamp,cell_id,site_id,serial_no,model_no,tac,current_date":"124545422342,VAT,1672804497000,28668,ULG2866,,,,20230104"}}
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"reference_key,service_type,event_timestamp,cell_id,site_id,serial_no,model_no,tac,current_date"}],"optional":false},"payload":{"reference_key,service_type,event_timestamp,cell_id,site_id,serial_no,model_no,tac,current_date":"124545422342,VAT,1672802056000,,,357416315997720F,,35741,20230104"}}
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"reference_key,service_type,event_timestamp,cell_id,site_id,serial_no,model_no,tac,current_date"}],"optional":false},"payload":{"reference_key,service_type,event_timestamp,cell_id,site_id,serial_no,model_no,tac,current_date":"0342455432268,VAT,1672802123000,,,357464315455830F,,35746,20230104"}}
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"reference_key,service_type,event_timestamp,cell_id,site_id,serial_no,model_no,tac,current_date"}],"optional":false},"payload":{"reference_key,service_type,event_timestamp,cell_id,site_id,serial_no,model_no,tac,current_date":"9907033485252,WHO,1672873387000,,,,,,20230104"}}
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"reference_key,service_type,event_timestamp,cell_id,site_id,serial_no,model_no,tac,current_date"}],"optional":false},"payload":{"reference_key,service_type,event_timestamp,cell_id,site_id,serial_no,model_no,tac,current_date":"0,TAX,1672873451000,,,,,,20230104"}}
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"reference_key,service_type,event_timestamp,cell_id,site_id,serial_no,model_no,tac,current_date"}],"optional":false},"payload":{"reference_key,service_type,event_timestamp,cell_id,site_id,serial_no,model_no,tac,current_date":"5456035928014,ADD,1672873451000,,,,,,20230104"}}
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"reference_key,service_type,event_timestamp,cell_id,site_id,serial_no,model_no,tac,current_date"}],"optional":false},"payload":{"reference_key,service_type,event_timestamp,cell_id,site_id,serial_no,model_no,tac,current_date":"5648136134038,ADD,1672873451000,,,,,,20230104"}}`
```

Now I need help on the correct/valid syntax to access some designated columns row values using the Kafka FilePulse Connect library and perform certain filtration (e.g **DropFilter**, **GrokFilter**) before publishing matching row records to the target Kafka topic.

I currently have the configurations below but the DropFilter and GrokFilter are not working..

```
name=connect-file-pulse-quickstart-csv
connector.class=io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.source.FilePulseSourceConnector
topic=connect-file-pulse-quickstart-csv
tasks.max=1

filters=ParseDelimitedRow,ParseGrokFilterRow,DropMatchedRow

# Delimited Row filter
filters.ParseDelimitedRow.extract.column.name=headers
filters.ParseDelimitedRow.trim.column=true
filters.ParseDelimitedRow.regex=\\|
filters.ParseDelimitedRow.type=io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.filter.DelimitedRowFilter

# Grok Row filter
filters.ParseGrokFilterRow.type=io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.filter.GrokFilter
#filters.ParseGrokFilterRow.pattern=(?i)vat|add
filters.ParseGrokFilterRow.source=message
filters.ParseGrokFilterRow.overwrite=message
filters.ParseGrokFilterRow.ignoreFailure=true

# Drop Row Filter
filters.DropMatchedRow.type=io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.filter.DropFilter
filters.DropMatchedRow.extract.column.name=headers
filters.DropMatchedRow.if={{ equals('$.'extract_struct_field($value, 0), 0) }}
filters.DropMatchedRow.invert=false

skip.headers=1
tasks.reader.class=io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.reader.LocalRowFileInputReader

# File Listing
fs.listing.filters=io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.filter.IgnoreHiddenFileListFilter,io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.filter.RegexFileListFilter
fs.listing.interval.ms=10000
fs.listing.directory.path=/my/target_directory
fs.listing.recursive.enabled=true
fs.listing.class=io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.LocalFSDirectoryListing

file.filter.regex.pattern=.*\\.csv$

fs.cleanup.policy.class=io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.clean.LogCleanupPolicy

# Internal Reporting
tasks.file.status.storage.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
tasks.file.status.storage.topic=connect-file-pulse-status

# Track file by name and hash
offset.attributes.string=name+hash
```

The DropFilter is meant to apply on the reference_key column with row(s) value as zero while the GrokFilter is to apply on service_type column with row(s) value as either VAT or ADD, case insensitive comparison.
Any help/solution to this challenge will be highly appreciated.